# How to access pixel data from video from webcam in JavaCV

Tags: java, webcam, javacv

I am trying to access pixel data from video from webcam in JavaCV.
This is the code i used to display video in screen.

```
CvCapture capture =opencv_highgui.cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
opencv_highgui.cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, opencv_highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720);
opencv_highgui.cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, opencv_highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 720);


IplImage grabbedimage = opencv_highgui.cvQueryFrame(capture);
CanvasFrame frame = new CanvasFrame("Camera");

while(frame.isVisible() && (grabbedimage = opencv_highgui.cvQueryFrame(capture))!=null){
    frame.showImage(grabbedimage);
}
```

Is it possible to covert IplImage to Buffered image. Can i access pixel data from buffered image.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have this little code here

```
IplImage originalImage = cvLoadImage(image);
BufferedImage bi=originalImage.getBufferedImage();
```